# How to disable submit button & links on-click in pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have challenged myself to create a visually dynamic and interactive experience in HTML and CSS only (No Javascript). So far, I haven't come across any feature I needed that I couldn't do in pure CSS and HTML. This one is perhaps a bit more difficult.

I need to prevent the user from double-clicking`<a>`, `<input type="submit">` and `<button>` tags. This is to prevent them double-submitting a form or accidentally making 2 GET requests to a URL. How can this be done in pure CSS? Even if we can't set `disabled` without JS, there should be some masking technique or combination of styles that can handle it here in 2020.

Here is a simple example of an attempt:

```css
.clicky:focus{
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#down" class="clicky">test</a>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p id="down">target</p>
```

Unfortunately, this disables it before the actual click event is fired for some reason. Maybe anchors aren't the best way to test? I will continue to make further attempts.

Comment: can you make the form give itself a class after it's been submitted the first time?

Comment: Maybe `pointer-events: all` by default, but not in the :active or :focus states? Like set `pointer-events: none` for those states?

Comment: maybe `el:active, el:focus` combined with pointer-events

Comment: Does this work? :active { display:none; // for example}

Comment: Added attempt. It disabled it before firing the click though.

Comment: Keep in mind: If you want to preventing double submissions, then it *MUST* be handled server-side. There is no way around it. A client-side (CSS/JS) solution  alone can always be circumvented (accidentally or maliciously) by the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea is to have a layer that come on the top of the element after the first click to avoid the second one.

Here is a basic idea where I will consider a duration of `1s` between two clicks that you can decrease. Try to click the button/link and you will notice that you can click again only after `1s`.

I am adding a small overlay to better see the trick

```css
.button {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.button span{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:100%;
  z-index:-1;
  animation:overlay 1s 0s; /* Update this value to adjust the duration */
  transition:0s 2s; /* not this one! this one need to be at least equal to the above or bigger*/
}


.button *:active + span {
  animation:none;
  bottom:0;
  transition:0s 0s;
}

@keyframes overlay {
  0%,100% {
    z-index:999;
    background:rgba(255,0,0,0.2); /* To illustrate */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <button>Click me</button>
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="button">
  <a href="#" onclick="console.log('clicked !')">Click me</a>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @AleksandrBelugin it's working fine, check the update. Maybe you did something wrong

Comment: I think it still let me click the button 2 times? I can see the button depress the second time.

Comment: @Paragon512 what browser? I tested this on Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @TemaniAfif when I do this `<a href="#" onclick="console.log('lalala')">Click me</a>` to link with rest of code nothing logs to console. imho it means link is not clicked

Comment: It looks like the best way to test this is with the `<a>` tag. I tried testing with submit buttons but monitoring the network inspector is weird and inconsistent. When I click the link, it doesn't fire the click. If you set a target to an anchor and click the link, it will disable the link but won't jump to the anchor.

Comment: @Paragon512 check the update. It should work now but with another drawback (will try to fix it)

Comment: @Paragon512 found a trick for the drawback ;) it should be fine now

Comment: Another problem. It prevents console log but not the important events such as navigate or form submit. Try wrapping the button in this: `<form action="https://google.com" method="GET" target="_blank">` and increase delay to like 20s

Comment: @Paragon512 show me the code your are using for the form here: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Paragon512 by the way, how you want to prevent navigation? if you click the link you are already in the new page so you cannot double click the same link while your are at the same page

Comment: @Paragon512 I see no issue, you can click the first time on both button and you either scroll or you submit the form. It's not what you want? I understood you want to avoid the second click

Comment: The user should only be allowed to click 1 time. The reason is that if you're resolved to not use any Javascript and the user submits a form, depending on the backend, it can sometimes take several seconds to process the form data. Same for a link for the same reason. If the user manages to accidentally or become inpatient and click again, the form or GET request might be repeated. It's a lot of extra code to deal with that possibility on the backend. Best if blocked on front-end. Click the button and then switch tabs and click again (Delay set high) it still lets you click again.

Comment: @Paragon512 you are setting the wrong delay, you need to increase the one of the animation and the one of the transition need to be equal or bigger .. if you check my answer I was talking about 1s and the 1s in the animation

Answer (score 0):

**The first solution**

The idea is to use `radio button` state by `:checked` to make modifications. We hide `radio` circle and when `:checked` for `<a>` make `pointer-events: none;` and for `buttons` with different types we hide them and show `disabled` ones.

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
}

#radio0, .my-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

#radio0 + a label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#radio0:checked+a {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.btn-one,
.btn-two {
  padding: 0;
}

.btn-one>label,
.btn-two>label {
  padding: 1px 6px;
}

.my-checkbox:checked+.btn-one {
  display: none;
}

.btn-two {
  display: none;
}

.my-checkbox:checked+.btn-one+.btn-two {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="radio0" type="radio" onclick="console.log('radio0 clicked!')">
  <a href="#">
    <label for="radio0">
        Click the link!
      </label>
  </a>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="radio1" class="my-checkbox">
  <button type="button" class="btn-one" onclick="console.log('radio1 clicked!')">
      <label for="radio1">Click the button!</label>
    </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn-two" onclick="console.log('radio1 NOT clicked!')" disabled>
        <label for="radio1">Click the button!</label>
      </button>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="radio2" class="my-checkbox">
  <button type="submit" class="btn-one" onclick="console.log('radio2 clicked!')">
    <label for="radio2">Submit!</label>
  </button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn-two" onclick="console.log('radio2 NOT clicked!')" disabled>
      <label for="radio2">Submit!</label>
    </button>
</div>
```

**The second solution**

This one suits for `links`. The idea is to use `:target`. Targe `element` is hidden firstly. Then when is targeted use `:target` to `pointer-events: none;` of `<a>`.

```css
#anchor {
  display: none;
}

#anchor:target {
  display: block;
}

#anchor:target+a {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="anchor"></span>
  <a href="#anchor" onclick="console.log('anchor clicked!')">Click the link!</a>
</div>
```